# Laravel + Beanstalkd: How to run "queue:listen" as a service

Tags: php, laravel, beanstalkd

I'm using Beanstalkd as a work queue in my project.

Now, my project is completed and I have to deploy it on VPS(production server).

There is something that confusing me! should I ssh to production server and manually type `php artisan queue:listen` ? (it's crap)

Is there any server to run `queue:listen` as service?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to run the queue in production. This will allow you to run the process in the background, specify the number of workers you want processing queued jobs and restart the queue should the process fail.

As for the queue you choose to use, that's up to you. In the past I've used Beanstalkd locally installed on an instance and Amazon SQS. The local instance was fine for basic email sending and other async tasks, SQS was great for when the message volume was massive and needed to scale. There are other SaaS products too such as IronMQ, but the usual reason people run into issues in production are because they're not using Supervisor.

You can install Supervisor with `apt-get`. The following configuration is a good place to start:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=8
stdout_logfile=/home/user/app.com/worker.log
```

This will do the following:

- Give the queue worker a unique name
- Run the `php artisan queue:work` command
- Automatically start the queue worker on system restart and automatically restart the queue workers should they fail
- Run the queue worker across eight processes (this can be increased or reduced depending on your needs)
- Log any output to `/home/user/app.com/worker.log`

To start Supervisor, you'd run the following (after re-reading the configuration/restarting):

```
sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
```

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration) gives you some more in-depth information about using Supervisor to run Laravel's queue processes.

Comment: Great explanation. This project will send more than 50,000 messages per day. I never used Beanstalkd. Should I go for Amazon SQS?

Comment: It's a great service and it sounds like your application makes heavy use of the queue so I'd say using SQS would be money well spent. The additional monitoring an metrics you get become very valuable when things start going wrong!

Comment: We use Beanstalkd over 3M ops per day, it's great as it's open-source there are good metrics available as well the great admin panel: https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console